# Navigate back in visual webgui

Tags: asp.net, navigation, visual-web-gui

I'm a newbie of ASP.NET world. I'm developing an app with asp.net and insiede of an aspx page i'm using a window form developed with visual webgui.
I've this problem: inside my form, i have a button wich has to rise an event equals to the page back button of the browser.
I tried to search informations about this, but i can't find anything unfortunately.
I think that i've to do something with the `HttpContext`. I tried with the `Redirect` function but my "previous page" is open always in a new browser window.
Can someone tell me a way on how to do this thing please?

Thank's
  Marco

EDIT *SOLVED*

```
button.RegisterClientAction("history.go( -1 )", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

Comment: I can't see the Response and the Request objects in my project.
I can access them only through 'HttpContext.Current.', but if i call a Redirect the page will open in a new window. Not in the same.

Comment: no way, if i try the solution with the false the browser tells me that a popup was blocked and the page remain the same.

Comment: Then i have no ideer what to do.. you dont have a target="_blank" in your link?

Comment: the link is correct. i tried to insert a manual link and it's always opened in a new browser window.